# ngClass is not working in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-class

ngClass directive generating the following error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.
```

code snippet.

```
 <li [ngClass]="{'active':true}"><a href="">Home</a></li>
```

NB: I already imported the common module

```
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common"
```

Library version angular 4.0.1

Comment: did you included the module aswell in the app.module imports part?

Comment: If the component under the root module make sure that BrowserModule is imported. If it is in a child module import CommonModule. These imports being missing will give you that error when trying to use common directives.

Answer (score 8):

As @Nedim suggested, if you are using `[ngClass]` within a feature module, you'd need to make sure that `CommonModule` is being added to the `imports: []` array property of `@NgModule({})`:

```
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common"

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

To conditionally add a single class based on a boolean value/expression I'd recommend you use the syntax `[class.someClass]="condition"`. Here is the documentation for [Class binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding).

```
<li [class.active]="true"><a href="">Home</a></li>
```

For example, to evaluate against a boolean class property to conditionally apply "active" CSS class:

**TS:**

```
export class App {
  foo: boolean = true;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div [class.active]="foo">Foobar</div>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/roRk8hVgC0Ye9idQQXQD?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality in action.

**Note:** If you are trying to apply some type of active styling related to the router, you could use the [RouterLinkActive](http://routerLinkActive=%22active%22) binding. The following example would apply the CSS class "active" when the user has activated the path "/heroes".

```
<a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
```

Comment: I'd imagine it's related to not having `CommonModule` added to `imports: []` of the feature module where `[ngClass]` is being used. I've updated to answer to suggest that addition. Probably will need more information from @Binson.